# What is S/P in "Tax Deduction S/P"?

Tags: tax-deduction, accounting, bookkeeping

This may be an unusual question, but I have a plugboard labeled "Tax Deduction S/P" for an IBM 402 accounting machine from the 1950s. This must have been used to process records on punched cards to generate a tax deduction report. But what is "S/P"? Is this an accounting term?

Edit: Michael C figured out that it stands for "summary punch", but here's a photo for the curious:
[image: IBM 403 plugboard for tax deductions]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the plugboard? Other symbols on it might be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. I'm not really sure this is a personal finance question.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be about personal finance.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - I figured the question was about money and accounting, but it turned out to be more technical. Should I delete the question? I don't want to rob Michael of his points.

Comment: Yes, you can delete. It will be closed either way. No worries about rep points, this is just how the board works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the manual, [SP means summary punching.](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/ibm/punchedCard/AccountingMachine/224-1614-13_402-403-419.pdf)

> Summary punching is the automatic preparation of one total card to
>   replace a group of detail cards.

Comment: Thanks! The board is wired for summary punching, so that must be it.